# Как сделать обработку нужной ошибки в try catch?

Tags: c#, ado.net

**Используется**
MySql
C#

**Цель**
Проверка на уникальность попадаемых данных в таблицу.

**Сценарий**
1. Код добавляет в таблицу БД в поле `ssl_str` ссылки типа `/csharp-net-page2.html`
Поле `ssl_str`индексировано: UNIQUE INDEX `ssl_str` (`ssl_str`)
2. При попадании в поле **неуникального** значения код возвращает ошибку

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Duplicate entry
>   '/csharp-net-page2.html' for key 'ssl_str'    в
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()    в
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow,
>   Int64& insertedId)    в MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResult(Int32
>   statementId, Int32& affectedRows, Int64& insertedId)    в
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean
>   force)    в MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()    в
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)    в MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

**Решение**
1. Как сделать, чтобы try catch обрабатывало именно эту ошибку?
Т.е. если возвращается именно эта ошибка, то запись добавляется в другую таблицу.
2. Является ли такой способ оптимальным для решения задачи по определению уникальности добавляемой записи или есть другие способы более оптимальные?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ловите соответствующий тип эксепшна:

```
try
{
    // попытка записи в базу
}
catch (MySqlException ex)
{
    if (ex.Number == 1586)
    {
        // обработка MySqlException исключения
    }
    else
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Список всех кодов исключения можно найти [здесь](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/error-messages-server.html).

> Является ли такой способ оптимальным для решения задачи по определению
>   уникальности добавляемой записи или есть другие способы более
>   оптимальные?

Можно и проверять на присутствие в БД самому, но, по-моему мнению, этот способ вполне действенный.

PS: Спасибо @Nikita и @Igor за поправки.

---

Тоже самое, с использованием `when-clause`, доступного с C# 6.0 и VS 2015

```
try
{
    // попытка записи в базу
}
catch (MySqlException ex) when (ex.Number == 1586)
{
    // обработка MySqlException исключения
}
```

Comment: если я правильно понял теорию, `ex` обрабатывает всё подряд. А как сделать, чтобы реагировал именно на сообщение(ошибке) об дубликате,  `Duplicate entry '/csharp-net-page2.html' for key 'ssl_str'`... или что является идентификатором типа ошибки....  P.S. я пока осваиваю C#, поэтому могу быть неточен в вопросах..

Comment: @koverflow `ex` - это ссылка на объект типа `MySqlException`. Обновил ответ.

Comment: @koverflow ваша ошибка имеет код 1586

Comment: @AGS17 - предложение: добавьте `else { throw; }` внутри `catch`.

Comment: @Igor спасибо, действительно так будет логичней

Comment: @Nikita спасибо, поправил.

Comment: Добавьте реализацию с `when-clause`